# Performs a search by multiple values - using an arrayList object

Tags: java

I have a problem with java that I have been trying to solve for several hours and can not.

I have an object of Ad, I use this object with arrayList.
I want to select the object of Ad - which are inside the arrayList - I want to select the object according to its attributes, I do this in the function:
I get attributes that an ad object has - I want to filter the Ad by attributes.

```
public class filterAds {
public class Ad {
        String domain;
        String role;
        String area;

        public Ad(String domain, String role, String area) {
            this.area = area;
            this.domain = domain;
            this.role = role;
        }
    }

    List<Ad> adList = new ArrayList<Ad>();

    public String[] getAds(String role, String domain, String area) {

        boolean filter = true;
        if(role != null)
        {
            //use it in search
        }
        if(area != null)
        {
            //use it in search
        }
        if(domain != null)
        {
            //use it in search
        }
        
        List<String> adIDsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < adList.size(); i++) {
            if (filter /* && also other conditions*/) {
                adIDsList.add(adList.get(i).id);
            }
        }
        
        String[] adIDs = new String[adIDsList.size()];;
        adIDs = adIDsList.toArray(adIDs);
        
        return adIDs;
}
}
```

I think the problem is not big, just need to fix the if conditions - but I have not been able to for hours.

Comment: where you are initializing `adList` list and what is the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: @roottraveller Thanks for the help, I created adList - I have not added an object to it yet, I am building the filtering function before

Comment: and what exactly is your issue?

Comment: thank for the willing to help, I want to select Ad objects, by different amount of properties, I want to check if I sent him a role - then filter by role, if it is null - then I do not want to filter by role, same thing for the area the domain

Comment: How the filtering mechanism should work exactly? You want to filter only byt the verfy first non-null value or use all of the given values to filter out objects from the list? You need "OR" or "AND" for your conditions join?

Comment: I want to filter with "and". For example with "role" and "domain" - they are not null, I also want to do filtering with "and" between them.

Comment: And what should happen when there is no value given, like all of the are `null`? All or none of the items should be listed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quite standard way to organize such search is:

```
List<String> adIDsList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < adList.size(); i++) {
    Ad ad = adList.get(i);
    if (
        (role == null || role.equals(ad.role)) &&
        (area == null || area.equals(ad.area)) &&
        (domain == null || domain.equals(ad.domain))
    ) {
        adIDsList.add(ad.id);
    }
}
```

so, we handle null and non-null in the same condition

Answer (score -2):

You can use stream api to filter data from list.
Below is the rough code that may give you idea how you can do.

```
List<String> adIDsList = adList.stream()
.filter(ad -> role.equals(ad.role))
.filter(ad -> domain.equals(ad.domain))
.filter(ad -> area.equals(ad.area))
.map(Ad::id)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: the filter is an `and` condition however what is required is `or`. should be `.filter(con1.or(con2).or(con3))`